# why typescript declare Promise.race twice in lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts?

Tags: typescript

```
/**
 * Creates a Promise that is resolved or rejected when any of the provided Promises are resolved
 * or rejected.
 * @param values An iterable of Promises.
 * @returns A new Promise.
 */
race<T>(values: Iterable<T>): Promise<T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? U : T>;

/**
 * Creates a Promise that is resolved or rejected when any of the provided Promises are resolved
 * or rejected.
 * @param values An iterable of Promises.
 * @returns A new Promise.
 */
race<T>(values: Iterable<T | PromiseLike<T>>): Promise<T>;
```

I thought the first one totally covers second one. If it is, does it mean the second one is useless? So I prefer it's not, and please tell me why we need the second one. Thanks a lot.